# How to patch only a particular hunk from a diff

Tags: diff, patch

Is there a way to apply a single hunk from a diff to a file?  For example, say I do a diff from file A and B, and that produces three chunks of differences, each denoted with something like...

```
@@ -971,30 +977,28 @@
```

...(in the case of *unified* diffs).  I'd then want to be able to feed that diff into stdin, and ask patch to only apply hunk N.

The manual method would be to cut-and-paste the interesting hunks, but I'm not after that kind of a solution.

Comment: In my past experience, it's just not very hard to read a context diff into an editor and prune it down. I don't really see the advantage of a complex argument structure for patch over that. Is there something in particular you are trying to do that makes this intractable?

Comment: Let's put it this way - if patch *did* support it - I *would* use it.  I have some vim macros that remove diff syntax so it's not too bad, but it would be easier to just type a single command.

Answer (score 12):

[filterdiff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/filterdiff) might help.

It allows extraction of subset of patches matching a variety of requirements, from one/many  patch files. For example, here we extract from the file `unified_diff.patch`, the patches applicable to files with name matching `one_file.c`, only to lines 950 to 1050 of the original file:

```
filterdiff -i *one_file.c --lines=950,1050 unified_diff.patch
```

To extract specific/range of hunks:

```
filterdiff --hunks=1,3,5-8,15 file.patch
```

Extracting patches from mail messages:

```
filterdiff message-with-diff-in-the-body > file.patch
```

etc.

Comment: Nice, very handy.

Comment: It's a pity it isn't included on Mac out of the box  (available from [patchutils](https://github.com/twaugh/patchutils))

Answer (score 0):

Some of the GUI diff/patch tools have a way to select blocks or even individual lines.  I know TortoiseDiff from TortoiseSVN can work this way.  I think I've seen windiff do it, but it's been a while since I had to use it.

As far as command line tools, I have not seen anything that will do what you are asking.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the man page, but felt that it must exist - and it's just my inability to find it.  So - patch itself has no native support for this - is that accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Emacs can not only edit diffs intelligently (including the ever-useful split-hunk operation), but can apply them one hunk at a time itself (avoiding the need to switch from the editor to run `patch`).